# Netsuite API throws 400 bad request

Tags: php, api, curl, postman, netsuite

I am trying to connect with Netsuite Customer API but it throws `"400 bad request"`

Here is my code in PHP

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://xxxxxxx-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customer/1",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => true,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=>false,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>false,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: OAuth realm=\"xxxxxxx_SB1\",oauth_consumer_key=\"consumer_key_xxxxxx\",oauth_token=\"auth_token_xxxxxxxx\",oauth_version=\"1.0\""
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
if (curl_errno($curl)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($curl);
}
var_dump($error_msg);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($response);
?>
```

Here above code I copied from postman. In a postman, it returns data but when I copied code for php in a file it is not working, Could anyone suggest me where I am going to wrong ?
My localhost url : `localhost/netsuite_api.php`

Comment: hey I'm also facing the same issue. How did  u solve this?

Comment: @matheenulla I solved this issue here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/316911/php-curl-netsuite-api-throws-invalid-login-and-login-audit-throws-invalidsignatu

Comment: Thank you so much for the link I will go through with that.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, the netsuite API returns `400` even where it should be a `401` according to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/netsuitecs_gs/NSTRW/NSTRW.pdf).

From the docs about the Authentication, you need to send more fields ([see page 169 following](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/netsuitecs_gs/NSATH/NSATH.pdf)):

```
Authorization:
 OAuth realm="12345",
 oauth_consumer_key="4a3ff6c251a55057bb1e62d8dc8998a0366e88f3a8fe735265fc425368b0f154",
 oauth_token="52cfe88fecf2e2b74e833e7dfc4cae79ff44c3ca9f696d61e2a7eac6c8357c3c",
 oauth_nonce="qUwlmPvtGCS4sHJe8F7x",
 oauth_timestamp="1462453273",
 oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_version="1.0",
```